# Youtube Scraping (List of Videos)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On a Youtube channel, I'm trying to get a list of videos listed in the channel. (i.e. link, title, view, etc)

Yet, my code doesn't return any object. Any help will be appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import re     
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


address = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCepWEz3BW6EMKA4CU-yGDMw/videos"

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
#driver.get(address)

#driver.maximize_window()



#body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
#for i in range(250):
#    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
#    time.sleep(1)



r = requests.get(address)
page = r.text
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
result=soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": 'videoId'})


print(result)
```

Comment: no divs with the class `videoId` on that page

Comment: videoId is an attribute then? If I form "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" +  "videoId", this is a link that should work. I just can't collect these vidoeId ...

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCepWEz3BW6EMKA4CU-yGDMw/videos"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

datas = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ytd-grid-renderer")
result = {"title":[], "link":[], "views":[]}
for data in datas:
    try:
        title = data.find_element_by_css_selector("#video-title").text
        result["title"].append(title)
    except:
        result["title"].append("")

    try:
        link = data.find_element_by_css_selector("#video-title").get_attribute("href")
        result["link"].append(link)
    except:
        result["link"].append("")

    try:
        views = data.find_element_by_css_selector("#metadata-line .ytd-grid-video-renderer:nth-child(1)").text
        result["views"].append(views)
    except:
        result["views"].append("")
# print(result)

browser.close()
```